# Extend UITextField to create shareable components

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a number of UITextField components I have added programmatically, they all seem to have a number of shared lines.

I'd like to extract these out to some sort of extension so I can share the code and reduce repeated lines.

I'm really struggling how I would do this though.

I have added some examples of these components below and would love some input on how I can achieve this please...

```
let usernameTextField: UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.placeholder = "Username"
    tf.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.03)
    tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    tf.autocorrectionType = .no
    tf.autocapitalizationType = .none
    tf.spellCheckingType = .no
    tf.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTextInputChange), for: .editingChanged)
    tf.addTarget(nil, action:Selector(("firstResponderAction:")), for:.editingDidEndOnExit)
    return tf
}()

let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.placeholder = "Password"
    tf.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.03)
    tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    tf.autocorrectionType = .no
    tf.autocapitalizationType = .none
    tf.spellCheckingType = .no
    tf.returnKeyType = .done
    tf.isSecureTextEntry = true
    tf.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTextInputChange), for: .editingChanged)
    tf.addTarget(nil, action:Selector(("firstResponderAction:")), for:.editingDidEndOnExit)
    return tf
}()
```

Comment: Please note that if those are instance properties, your code is illegal. You cannot speak of `self` (as in your `addTarget` call) while initializing an instance property of `self`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach.  Use an extension to set the common properties like so...

```
extension UITextField{

    func initCommonProperties(withPlaceholder placeholder:String){

        backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.03)
        font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        borderStyle = .roundedRect
        autocorrectionType = .no
        autocapitalizationType = .none
        spellCheckingType = .no
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTextInputChange), for: .editingChanged)
        addTarget(nil, action:Selector(("firstResponderAction:")), for:.editingDidEndOnExit)
        self.placeholder = placeholder
    }
}

let usernameTextField: UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.initCommonProperties(withPlaceholder:"Username")
    return tf
}()

let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.initCommonProperties(withPlaceholder:"Password")
    return tf
}()
```

You can also do the same with a function instead of an extension

```
class MyTextFieldUtils{

    static func initCommonProperties(tf:UITextField){

        tf.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.03)
        tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        tf.autocorrectionType = .no
        tf.autocapitalizationType = .none
        tf.spellCheckingType = .no
        tf.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTextInputChange), for: .editingChanged)
        tf.addTarget(nil, action:Selector(("firstResponderAction:")), for:.editingDidEndOnExit)
    }
}

let usernameTextField: UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    MyTextFieldUtils.initCommonProperties(tf)
    tf.placeholder = "Username"
    return tf
}()

let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    MyTextFieldUtils.initCommonProperties(tf)
    tf.placeholder = "Password"
    return tf
}()
```

The advantage of the former is a much simpler API. The drawback is now *all* UITextFields will get the `initCommonProperties` function.

The advantage of the latter is it separates concerns completely, but at the expense of being more verbose.  However, you can create different initializers for different types of TextBoxes (or any controls) by either creating multiple functions, or multiple classes, each with the same function.

Another approach is to create convenience initializers via an extension, like so...

```
extension UITextField{

    convenience init(withPlaceholder placeholder:String){

        self.init()

        backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.03)
        font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        borderStyle = .roundedRect
        autocorrectionType = .no
        autocapitalizationType = .none
        spellCheckingType = .no
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTextInputChange), for: .editingChanged)
        addTarget(nil, action:Selector(("firstResponderAction:")), for:.editingDidEndOnExit)
        self.placeholder = placeholder
    }
}

let usernameTextField = UITextField(withPlaceholder:"Username")
let passwordTextField = UITextField(withPlaceholder:"Password")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is no "shareable components" issue here. The only ugliness is that your code is not DRY ("don't repeat yourself"). So make it DRY! Just factor out the common repeated code into a function that can be called from all your text field creation code. For example, let's say you're doing all this in `viewDidLoad`. Then the code you showed can be factored out like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    func makeTextField() -> UITextField {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.03)
        tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        tf.autocorrectionType = .no
        tf.autocapitalizationType = .none
        tf.spellCheckingType = .no
        tf.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTextInputChange), for: .editingChanged)
        tf.addTarget(nil, action:Selector(("firstResponderAction:")), for:.editingDidEndOnExit)
        return tf
    }
    let usernameTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = makeTextField()
        tf.placeholder = "Username"
        return tf
    }()
    let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = makeTextField()
        tf.placeholder = "Password"
        tf.returnKeyType = .done
        tf.isSecureTextEntry = true
        return tf
    }()
    // ... do something with text fields here ...
}
```

Comment: Just a friendly comment.  When you refer to things like 'DRY', you should make the first reference a link so others can delve right into its meaning.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is simply to subclass `UITextField` and include the shared lines in an overridden `init` method. You would then create instances of your subclass rather than `UITextField` directly.

Example:

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.03)
        self.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        self.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        self.autocorrectionType = .no
        self.autocapitalizationType = .none
        tfselfspellCheckingType = .no
    }
}

let passwordTextField = MyTextField()
...
```

Comment: Yep. Agree with @LeoDabus.  This looks to be a cut-copy-paste error since you're referring to 'tf' when you should just be setting the properties directly.

Comment: @LeoDabus Good spot, yeah I did copy paste the OPs code here, will make the change and take note to check in future.